# RetrieveAPI in DjangRESTFramework is not working

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to get an instance of API in 127.0.0.1:8000/api/1 but I get 
list of APIs as in 127.0.0.1:8000/api. IN fact anything after 
/api/ like 127.0.0.1:8000/api/asfddas gives the same output

```
views.py

class ArticleListView(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset=Article.objects.all()
serializer_class=ArticleSerializer

class ArticleDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
queryset=Article.objects.all()
serializer_class=ArticleSerializer

urls.py
urlpatterns=[
url('',ArticleListView.as_view()),
url('<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view()),
]


picture of 127.0.0.1:8000/api/1
Article List

Article List
GET /api/1
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
{
    "title": "Test debut",
    "content": "this is the debut for the test",
    "description": "2019-10-22 08:46:05.964656+00:00"
},
{
    "title": "2nd Test",
    "content": "This is the second test article for the djreact 
app",
    "description": "2019-10-22 08:46:05.964656+00:00"
},
{
    "title": "3rd article",
    "content": "content for 3rd article",
    "description": "description for 3rd article"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change like this:

```
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets
class ArticleListView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, generics.ListAPIView):


class ArticleDetailView(viewsets.GenericViewSet, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
```

change url.py:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'article', ArticleListView)
router.register(r'article', ArticleDetailView)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

and your api detail become :
`127.0.0.1:8000/api/article/1/`